# Random number from exponential distribution with a scale parameter

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

I have been using $r = \mu \ln(1 - n)$ to obtain pseudo-random numbers from an exponential distribution, where $\mu$ is the distribution mean and $n$ is a pseudo-random number from 0 to 1.  Now I want to do the same thing, but use a distribution that has a scale parameter.  Can I simply scale the result of the above equation?

Also, why does my source recommend using $\ln(1 - n)$?  Isn't $\ln(n)$ effectively the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your first question:  yes.  You simply scale $r$ via $\mu$; in fact, $\mu$ *is* the scale parameter for an exponential distribution.

Answer to your second question:  because $\ln (1-n)$ is an **order-preserving** transformation; that is, if $X \sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1)$, then $Y = -\mu \ln (1 - X) \sim {\rm Exponential}(\mu)$.  As $X \nearrow 1$, $Y \nearrow \infty$.  If you do not need this property, it is just as valid to simply write $\ln X$ instead.

Comment: Thank you.  What do the slanted arrows mean?

Comment: loosely: "As X increases to 1, Y increases to infinity"

Comment: @heropup re them being the same aside from one not being order-preserving -- correct, except for the additional issue that most rngs are on $[0,1)$, and $\ln 0$ - while only occurring very rarely - is problematic, while $\ln(1-1^-)$ might not be a problem, depending on the precise situation with the particular RNG and how it's dealt with.  [Where here $1^-$ is the largest value output by the uniform RNG.]